# Getting the sum of a list that is outside a function in Python 3.7.x

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-3.7

> Okay, so my program has a function that collects the order numbers in
>   a menu that the user chooses. It runs as a loop so if anyone wants to
>   order another item, the can choose to do so. So far everything is
>   running smoothly, the list does collect the item numbers, but I have
>   another function that calculates the subtotal of the bill that is not
>   doing its job. I am bringing in the list and the items collected, but
>   it is not doing the math. I even tried putting it in a loop, but I
>   can't figure out how to get past this.
>
> Here's the relevant sections of my code:

---

```
# declarations
master_list = []  # stores lists (i.e. menu_choice), perhaps to print receipt
menu_choice = []  # stores menu numbers


def user_order():
    proceed = "Y"  # starts as true
    while proceed in ["Y", "YES"]:
        choice = input("Enter item number you would like to order: ")
        while choice not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]:  # only allows a valid list choice
            print("Invalid entry. Please choose an item between 1 and 6.")
            choice = input("Enter item number you would like to order: ")
        menu_choice.append(choice)  # fills the empty list
        master_list.append(menu_choice)
        return choice  # returns only one choice at a time


def det_proceed():
    proceed = input("\nWould you like to order another item (Y or N)? ").upper()
    while proceed not in ["Y", "YES", "N", "NO"]:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid choice (Y or N).")
        proceed = input("\nWould you like to order another item? ").upper()
    if proceed in ["Y", "YES"]:  # if yes, whole program runs again via functions
        display_menu(), user_order(), det_proceed()


def calc_order(menu_choice, choice):
    # store order values
    order_subtotal = []
    for x in range(len(menu_choice)):
        if choice in menu_choice == "1":
            order = 10
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        if choice in menu_choice == "2":
            order = 8.75
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        if choice in menu_choice == "3":
            order = 9.5
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        if choice in menu_choice == "4":
            order = 10.25
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        if choice in menu_choice == "5":
            order = 9.5
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        if choice in menu_choice == "6":
            order = 11.25
            order_subtotal.append(order)
        subtotal = sum(order_subtotal)
        print("Subtotal:", subtotal)
        return subtotal


def prnt_bill(subtotal):
    print("\t\t Bill Information \t\t")
    print("_" * 50)
    print("Subtotal:\t\t\t", subtotal)
    print("\t\t\t\t\t", "_" * 10)


subtotal = calc_order(menu_choice, choice)
prnt_bill(subtotal)
```

Comment: When you call `calc_order(menu_choice, choice)`, `menu_choice` is an empty list. So what are you expecting to happen? The for loop doesn't do anything, so nothing returns.

Comment: My thoughts were that ```menu_choice``` would be populated by the valid inputs selected by the user allowing me to reference what would be on the bill. Although, I see what you mean now. But how would I use it when it is populated? I thought the list wasn't empty because when I tested it with a simple print statement, it had the choices in it.

Comment: It looks like you just need to run `det_proceed()` first.

Comment: How is that supposed to help?

Comment: That will call `user_order()`, which will gradually populate menu choices... Have you tested just the function by providing `calc_order()` with a filled list

Comment: I've just seen the actual problem. I'll make a full post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `calc_order` function. I'm not entirely sure what that function is meant to do. What you've written looks like it's meant to be

> Given a list of menu choices, and a specific choice, calculate the total for that choice.

If that's what you were intending, it's not a great way of doing it. What I think you probably mean to do is

> Given a list of menu choices, calculate the total for the order.

---

None of the `if` statements do anything because

```
if choice in menu_choice == "1":
```

doesn't mean anything. `choice` is a int. `menu_choice == "1"` always evaluates to False because `menu_choice` is a list. So the comparison you are doing is `<some int> == False`.

I don't understand why you would give the choice as an argument. If you want to know the number of each thing in the list you can use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(menu_choices)

# -> { 1: 0, 1: 3, 1: 1, ... }
```

Note the keys are integers because you are using `input()` rather than `raw_input()`. `input()` automatically converts numbers.

Then you could loop through that to find out either the subtotal for each item.

---

I think what's more likely is that you're just trying to get the total for everything in `menu_choices`. I've got two options.

#### Using Counter

```
from collections import Counter

def calc_order(menu_choice):
    counter = Counter(menu_choice)
    prices = { 1: 10.0, 2: 8.75, 3: 9.5, 4: 10.25, 5: 9.5, 6: 11.25 }
    total = 0
    for key, v in counter.items():
        total += prices[key] * v
    return total
```

#### Looping through like before

```
def calc_order(menu_choice):
    subtotal = 0
    for choice in menu_choice:
        if choice == 1:
            subtotal += 10
        elif choice == 2:
            subtotal += 8.75
        # ... can't be bothered to type everything out
        else:
            subtotal += 11.25
     # print(f'Subtotal: {subtotal}')
     return subtotal
```